# Why you shouldn't start with jQuery

Tags: javascript, angular

I started web development on `jQuery` and now I'm on a `Angular 6` project and I can't even serialise a form because it doesn't exist.

How can I serialize the form so I can send it with post?

The form id is `settingsForm`

```
saveSettings() {
    let form = document.getElementById("settingsForm");
    console.log(form);
}
```

My service

```
saveSettings(settingsData) {
    return this._http.post(RequestProperties.baseUrl + "/settings/save",settingsData, this.options);
}
```

Comment: What has the title to do with the actual question/problem? And where is the jQuery part? O.o

Comment: Why you should start with [ask] should become obvious, once you actually do. The question title is extremely bad, and what you actually want to know is rather unclear, to me at least, as well.

Comment: I just want to serialize the data so I can send it on my service

Comment: @user9833245 use JSON.stringify to POST the data.

Comment: @user9833245 in angular you have to use either template or reactive form to get the value of form controls , directly working with form id is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

Using angular you should reference document. If you do your probably going about something the wrong way and you are not letting Angular do the heavy lifting for you.

Using [form controls](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) for forms gives you a lot of flexibility, validation, and control over the inputs. [Here](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#post) is the API for posting.